# Vista basada en clases no guarda imagen

Tags: django

tengo el siguiente codigo donde envio por un formulario una imagen y otros datos todo graba bien excepto la imagen esta no se guarda(url) a pesar de tener mi form asi:

```
 <form role="form" action="{% url 'productos:crear_producto' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
...
</form>
```

Este es mi codigo de la vista

```
class CrearProducto(SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):

    model = Producto
    form_class = ProductoForm
    template_name = "administrador/crear_producto.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("productos:administrar_productos")
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        from django.conf import settings
        CODIGO_INICIAL_AUTOMATICO = settings.CODIGO_INICIAL_AUTOMATICO
        try:
            producto = Producto.objects.latest('id')
            codigo = int(producto.cod_auxiliar) + 1
        except Producto.DoesNotExist:
            codigo = CODIGO_INICIAL_AUTOMATICO

        context = super(CrearProducto, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['codigo_producto'] = str(codigo).zfill(13)
        return context
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.POST:
            form = ProductoForm(request.POST)
            self.object = form.save()
            producto_actual = Producto.objects.get(nombre=self.object.nombre)
            movimiento = Movimientos(
                tipo = 1,
                proveedor = self.object.proveedor,
                producto = self.object,
                bodega = self.object.bodega,
                vunitario_promedio = float(self.object.precio),
                responsable = request.user,
                vunitario_compra = float(self.object.precio),
                cant_ingreso = self.object.cantidad,
                tot_ingreso = float(self.object.cantidad) * float(self.object.precio),
                tot_saldo = float(self.object.cantidad) * float(self.object.precio),
                cant_saldo = self.object.cantidad,
            )
            movimiento.save()

            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Registro creado con  éxito')
            return redirect('productos:administrar_productos')
```

si lo hago de la siguiente forma :

```
class CrearProducto(SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):

    model = Producto
    form_class = ProductoForm
    template_name = "administrador/crear_producto.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("productos:administrar_productos")
```

graba bien todos los datos entonces me da a entender que en def post esta fallando al grabar mi imagen.

Mi model la imagen lo defino asi:

```
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=300)
imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='productos/', null=True, blank=True)
..
...
```

Quiza alguna sugerencia gracias de antemano.

Comment: No le estás pasando los archivos, deberías tener algo como esto `form = ProductoForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)`. Siempre puedes revisar la implementación de `CreateView` desde [esta](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_form_kwargs) página

Comment: @GermanAlzate en efecto eso era "form = ProductoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)"..gracias..!!